# php mysql code to delete data from multiple table having same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form from where Information is entered into multiple database having same id, if by mistake wrong data is entered, I want to delete that from all tables.

How and what should I do to delete from all information related to that id from all tables.

Comment: And this, folks, is why we use foreign keys, referential integrity, and `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: If you are using MySQL, use InnoDB Tables and referential constraints. It will automatically handle data consistency.

Comment: I haven't specified foreign key in database table whereas my id is being inserted by the I have written. cascade delete works on foreign key provided in database.

Comment: the person handling database has not used InnoDB tables and I can't change it as it is already on server. I have to do something with the codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple table deletes:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

For example say you had 4 tables and want to delete all the records in 3 of them that relate to the 1st table:-

```
DELETE Table1, Table2, Table3
FROM Table0
INNER JOIN Table1
ON Table0.Id = Table1.ParentId
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table0.Id = Table2.ParentId
INNER JOIN Table3
ON Table0.Id = Table3.ParentId
WHERE Table0.Id = 1
```

Of course you could also delete from the first table (Table0) as well.